# how to properly call photobooth.js

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to use [photobooth.js](http://wolframhempel.github.io/photobooth-js/) to make a simple photobooth page. I know very little about JS and webpages, but it seemed the best solution for what I have in mind. My problem is that when I load the script (no dependencies, according to the website) and try to use it in my basic app, nothing happens, so obviously I'm not calling the script properly. To make sure the script is loaded, I added a `ShowAlert()` function to `photobooth.js` that I use in an `onload="ShowAlert()"` statement, which indeed triggers the alert.

So adding `myPhotobooth = new Photobooth( document.getElementById( "container" ) );` to my page does not work as [advertised here](http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/12/add-an-html5-webcam-to-your-site-with-photobooth-js/) (or more likely I don't understand how to use that)

Would someone please explain what I am missing?

The modified `photobooth_min.js` source:

```
/**
*
* Photobooth.js version 0.7

*CUSTOM DEBUG CODE
*/
function ShowAlert() {
    alert('show this message');
}
/**
*Rest of photobooth_min.js code, unmodified.
*/
```

my `index.html` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>photobooth</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="photobooth_min.js" onload="ShowAlert()"></script>

    <script>
        myPhotobooth = new Photobooth( document.getElementById( "example" ) ); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

my directory structure:

[image: directory stucture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call external script files, you shouldn't have anything inside...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="WebContent/photobooth_min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myPhotobooth = new Photobooth( document.getElementById( "example" ) ); 
</script>
```

the other thing is the `path` to the file, in this case, and assuming you have this HTML in a file called `index.html` the structure you are setting is:

```
|--- index.html
|--- WebContent (folder)
      |--- photobooth_min.js
```

to start, put all in the same folder like:

```
|-- index.html
|-- photobooth_min.js
```

and reference the script only as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="photobooth_min.js"></script>
```

P.S. remember that the `photobooth` script will never work on IE and Safari ... the 2 most used browsers in both Windows an Mac platforms...

Comment: Thanks. I edited my code and directory structure following your advice, as you can see from the edits I made to my question. However, the problem persists. To avoid mistakes, what I did was clone the GitHub repo of photobooth.js, and replace its index.html with mine, so clearly I am still calling the script wrong. I also tried to decipher the code from the original index.html from the repo, but couldn't find where the call to photobooth.js was made... :-S I am using Firefox 34.0.5

Comment: Ok, I proceeded by slicing chunks of the original index.html until I arrived to a minimal solution. I still don't fully understand how this works, but let's consider the issue closed. Thank you!